# log4j does not work desktop (setup install) application in java

Tags: java, installation, log4j

I am trying to log my application. I am getting logs properly when i run application on eclipse. But I create a setup installation file and my logs does not seems. How can i solve this cause?

Comment: Put log4j.xml and include the log4j JARs in the CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your log4j.properties file and log4j*.jar inside your final jar file.

This is how jar looks inside:
[image]

Comment: i use pom.xml and it is desktop application. log4j.properties file inside src/main/resources path.

Comment: what is inside your jar file?

Comment: log4j jar file. version 1.2.16